# How long can an unstable particle live? Is there a theoretical upper limit?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, elementary-particles, weak-interaction

Somehow, in all my years of studying and reading, I have never come across an answer to this question....

Is there a fundamental limit to the lifetime of even the shortest-lived subatomic particles, the so-called 'resonance' particles?

I wonder if there is a list somewhere of the longest-lived muon ever measured, tauon, pion, etc.....

Comment: Uhm... why should there be? Decay is just a probabilistic process, as time goes to infinity, the not-having-decayd-yet-probability goes to zero, but only asymptotically...

Comment: You must make clear in your question that you are not talking about the established or hypothesized *mean lifetimes*, commonly referred to as "lifetime"s.

Comment: The proton may be unstable under some theories, with no measurement of a lifetime as of yet. So pretty much anything up to infinity...

Comment: @Jon Custer  Looks like the OP is not asking about conceptual mean lifetimes of unobserved decays, but observed points in decay distributions with fixed mean lifetimes. That' what I invited him to confirm or deny....

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a theoretical upper limit?

As the theory describes the decay distribution with an exponential, of course there is no theoretical limit.

> Is there a fundamental limit to the lifetime of even the shortest-lived subatomic particles, the so-called 'resonance' particles?

There is the pragmatic limit of how long an experiment to measure the lifetime takes,   and once the theoretical formula is plotted with data there is even  no reason to keep detecting or redoing an experiment to check for the end of the distribution event lifetime. What for?

So

> I wonder if there is a list somewhere of the longest-lived muon ever measured, tauon, pion, etc.....

No, there would not be because it is an irrelevant point to the search for the theory of particle physics. Once  a mathematical form is defined accurately  the goal of the experiment  has been fulfilled.

Of course there exists the ["oh my God"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oh-My-God_particle) particle

> The Oh-My-God particle (OMG particle) was an ultra-high-energy cosmic ray detected on 15 October 1991 by the Fly's Eye camera in Dugway Proving Ground, Utah, U.S. At that time it was the highest-energy cosmic ray that had ever been observed.

...

> The Oh-My-God particle's energy was estimated as $(3.2±0.9)×10^{20}$ eV

...

> The energy of this particle is some 40 million times that of the highest energy protons that have been produced in any terrestrial particle accelerator

...

> Since the first observation, at least seven similar events (energy $5.7×10^{19}$ eV or greater) have been recorded, confirming the phenomenon.

...

> More recent studies using the Telescope Array Project have suggested a source of the particles within a 20-degree radius "warm spot" in the direction of the constellation Ursa Major.

So if you are so much interested and good at relativistic kinematics, you good get an upper limit to the longest lived muon, if it were a muon. The linked article gives numbers assuming it was a proton .